# Why are my Dash icons empty?

Tags: 11.10, unity-dash, icons

I just ran the Update Manager this morning which required a restart. After the restart this is what my Dash looks like:

[image: empty dash icons]

The empty icons are:

- Home Folder
- Terminal
- gedit
- Trash

Comment: have you tried removing your empty favorites and again adding it.

Comment: That worked for Home Folder, Terminal, and gedit, but there is no option to remove Trash from the Launcher.

Comment: trash can be removed .. only workspace switcher can't be removed. Only by some tweaks you can remove it. Try to reset the dash icons by "unity --reset-icons" command .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to the terminal and type    unity --reset-icons

Comment: Had to run with sudo for it to have an effect. Running with sudo caused it to lock up Unity and any open windows forcing a restart. But after the restart the icons were reset and back to normal. Regardless, this fixed it for me. Thanks!